# Checking if content is in web.config

Tags: powershell

I want to add content to a web config, but only if that content does not already exist. This is what I do:

```
$webconfig = Get-Content F:\whatever\web.config
if ($webconfig -notlike "*WebGrease*" ) {
  // do stuff here
}
```

Now my problem is: Even if the web.config contains something like

```
<dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.3.0.0" newVersion="1.3.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
```

it still enters the code at "do stuff here". What is the problem? Doesn't "notlike" work with multi-line - strings?

Comment: `Get-Content` puts the lines into an array, so `$webconfig` is not a multi-line string here

Comment: Ah. Thanks for that. In Debugging it looked like a string. That fooled me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily find the string using [`Select-String`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849903.aspx) (which accepts `regex` for `-Pattern`):

```
if(-not(Select-String -Pattern "WebGrease" -Path "F:\whatever\web.config")) {
    // do stuff here
}
```

Since you are using an XML file, as suggested by [@Mathias R. Jessen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen) you could directly target the node with [`Select-Xml`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849968.aspx) instead:

```
if(-not(Select-Xml -Xml "F:\whatever\web.config" -XPath '//assemblyIdentity[@name = "WebGrease"]')) {
    // do stuff here
}
```

Comment: If OP is always looking for a specific configuration element, `Select-Xml -Xml $wc -XPath '//assemblyIdentity[@name = "WebGrease"]'` might be a safer option